# I would like to add a second column to my uitableview. How?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I currently have a table view with one column and static information. I would like to add a second column with information that will updated from a server.

Here is my code right now:

```
var array = ["Daskalakis Athletic Center" , "Hagerty Library", "Hans Dining Hall", "Northside Dining Hall", "Urban Eatery", "Creese Student Center", "Cyber Learning Center", "Rush Advisors"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.ListView
        .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: first clear your question bro. if u add coloum in your table then u can add in array first .

Comment: what u want in table ?

Comment: cant you just subclass UITableViewCell, add two textLabel horizontally ?

Comment: I want to have information to correspond to the various array values be displayed in the second column and that information would be taken from a server that updates the app every few minutes. I do not know how to do what you suggested.

Comment: you are saying for eample first column first field will be Daskalakis Athletic Center and second column first field will be Daskalakis Athletic Center's value from server ?

Comment: Correct, how would i do that?

Comment: use collectionview tableview cannot work for this requirement

Answer (score 1):

As Eugene suggested, you may need to rewrite the implementation and need to use UICOllectionView instead of UITableView.

An alternate approach is, you design the cell in such a way that it looks like it have two coloumns (Reduce the cell content view width to half and replicate the same view and align it to other half, you can also add a vertical separator in between both).

Answer (score 0):

You may use UICollectionView instead UITableView. Or you can use second UITableView.